# How to remove n lines from txt-file in R?

Tags: r

I have txt-files with data arranged in columns, but with a fixed number of textlines (12 in this casee) with comments/general info. I need to remove these textlines (l. 1-12) in order to be able to read the files as a dataframe. Can this be done in R?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `skip` argument of `read.table`:

```
read.table(text=' bla
           bla
           x y
           1 2',header=TRUE,skip=2)
  x y
1 1 2
```

Or using `readLines` and remove the first 12 rows.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `skip` arugment to read.table:

```
read.table("file.txt", skip=12)
```

From the help:

> `skip` integer: the number of lines of the data file to skip before
>   beginning to read data.